# Access sql count multiple fields with day() function

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, group-by

I have a table like this.

```
Name   ID    BirthDate
Bob    1     01/09/2010
jojo   2     02/09/2012
```

Where PK is joint of Name and ID, I want to count in each day (1,2,...),how many people share the same day(just day, ignoring month and year). I know I have to use day() function. I try:

```
   Select count(Name & ID)
   from Table
   group by day(BirthDate);
```

Comment: Given that primary key, you should be using `COUNT(*)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count(*)` counts rows - it should fit your bill:

```
SELECT   DAY(BirthDate), COUNT(*)
FROM     MyTable
GROUP BY DAY(BirthDate)
```